# Godot / GDScript: Autocomplete not working

Tags: autocomplete, code-completion, godot, gdscript

So, I started learning with the 3.0 RC1 version of the Godot Engine and I noticed, that code completion isn't working. No suggestions, no completions, nothing. Only highlighting and bracket completion works. Is that because of the RC1 or am I missing something? Code completion is enable in editor settings.

Thanks alot.

Greetings, Nils

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this myself. I just weren't writing the code inside the scene functions.

Answer (score 1):

Since Godot 3.1 you can use typed variables in GDScript like this:

```
var myTexture : ImageTexture
```

And then autocomplete will work a little better for those. Otherwise Godot can not always figure out what type your variable is.